# Complex Numbers Simple Question Argument

Tags: complex-numbers

Is there a geometric explanation of how the arguments changes when 2 complex numbers in mod-arg form are multiplied or divided together? Like I don't understand the reason it changes like that.

Answer (score 1):

Well all you basically do, say if the two complex numbers have the same modulus, you just add the angles together for multiplication.

If its cis(2/3 pi) x cis (2/3 pi) then you will geting cis (4/3 pi) where graphically you can see you add the two angles added together, 120 degrees + 120 degrees. I'm sure someone else will explain it better